# NO display with raspberry Pi.High voltage at 3.3V output.(Is it dead?)

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, display, gsm, recovery

Recently I was using raspberry pi which was working fine. I tried to use GSM module with it and powered it using the 3.3V pin of raspberry pi and suddenly my raspberry pi rebooted and after it gained power again, there was no activity i.e keyboard and mouse were not working(display was there). I rebooted it again but the display was gone and still I have no display.

Plus when I connected GSM module it was also powered up with a 6.6V external power supply which I later checked was also available on the ports through which I tried to  gave 3.3V to GSM from Raspberry.

I think the voltage backfired.

IS my raspberry pi dead. ANY HELP PLEASE!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It is most likely dead.

Comment: Perhaps examining the [status lights](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Power_.2F_Start-up) can reveal what's going on?

Comment: @hydraxan14 Status: Red and green both are blinking, Red light is blinking after a specific interval so as green light. processor is getting insanely hot in a short period of time.

Answer (score 1):

### Power Problems

[A blinking red light indicates power problems.](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Red_power_LED_is_blinking)

> A blinking red power LED indicates problems with the power supply. On
>   model A and B, it is hard-wired to the 3.3V power supply rail. If it
>   is blinking, as one user has reported it means the 5V power supply
>   is dropping out. Use a different power supply.
>
> On model B+ (and presumably also the A+), the circuit has been
>   improved to give a much more reliable warning of poor power quality.
>   The red power LED is wired to an APX803 supervisor which kicks in
>   when the 5V power supply drops below 4.63V. If it does, the LED
>   will blink. Check your connections, cable, and power supply.

If changing out your pi's power supply does not fix the issue, then I think your pi is dead.

Comment: i changed my power supply, but the issue is still there.(I think it is officially dead). One thing that is still telling me to not give up on pie is that whenever   I turn on my pi without sd card, the red light works fine and never blinks but as soon as I plug it with a sd card it goes again blinking. I have flashed my card with new operating system but still no luck.